# How can I set a priority order between processes for uploading data on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, internet, upload, priority

Several processes are uploading data. How can I set a priority order between processes for uploading data on Windows 10? E.g., processing1.exe get 90%  of the bandwidth regardless of the other processes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Windows 10 does not offer any way to set a priority order between processes for uploading data. A third-party solution may be able to do that.